# why valgrind report the size of a pointer in a 64bit program as 4 bytes

Tags: c++, valgrind

I wrote a test C++ program to check the output of valgrind. The code is

```
#include <iostream>

void f() {
    int *pp = new int(1);
    std::cout << "pp is " << *pp << "\n";
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

The valgrind command I used is

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

The output from Valgrind is

```
==2255== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2255==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==2255==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==2255== 
==2255== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==2255==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2255==    by 0x400786: f() (in /run/shm/a.out)
==2255==    by 0x4007CC: main (in /run/shm/a.out)
==2255== 
==2255== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2255==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==2255==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2255==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2255==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2255==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I am using a Ubuntu machine:
    Linux Sun 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 14:25:57 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc version "4.6.3"

gcc parameter I used "-g -m64"

I think it should be eight bytes, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be eight bytes unless `sizeof(int)==8` on your platform.

You're allocating, and leaking, a single `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: yes. I think you are right since int is 4 bytes in my platform.

Answer (score 0):

Your do not allocate a pointer array, but an integer array of size one. So you are allocating only the size of an integer in memory. The only thing that is pointer is the local variable that stores the adress of your newly allocated array.

If you want to allocate a pointer, do `void **arr = new void*[1];`

Comment: Yes, because pointer on 64bit platform are 8 generally bytes long.

Comment: I mark Mat's answer as the answer to my question since he is the first one answered.